# How to read CSV files with blank lines and extra headers in Mule dataweave

Tags: regex, csv, groovy, mule, dataweave

I have CSV having blank line and extra herder below that like this:

```
**blank line**
Available_Date_Feed
productID,availableDate
148305801,2015-08-07T00:00:00.000+0000
160611862,2015-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000
160611715,2015-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000
160342798,2015-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000
```

I want to read values of productID & availableDate. If we do regular transformation with dataweave it will return null values

This is the code I have wrote in dataweave:

```
%dw 1.0
%input in0 application/csv headers=true
%output application/java
---
payload  map  {
    productID:$.productID,
    availableDate:$.availableDate
}
```

Returning payload as :

```
[{productID=null, availableDate=null}, {productID=null, availableDate=null}, {productID=null, availableDate=null}, {productID=null, availableDate=null}]
```

Any suggestions here?
Can we use Groovy/MEL/regex expression for this?
How to use Rows to ignore in Dataweave?

Can we Skip first 2 lines using groovy/regex?

**I am facing performance issue with the below groovy. Mule taking too much time to convert even 1 MB file. Is there any another solution for this?**

Answer (score 0):

I have used Groovy to skip the first 2 lines. This script fetch the comma separated values directly

```
 csvContent = message.payload
def filteredContent = new StringBuffer()
regexPattern = /(\S*),(\S*)/
finder = csvContent =~ regexPattern

(0..<finder.count).each {
    //println "Iteration: ${it+1}:"
    filteredContent.append(finder[it][0])
    filteredContent.append('\n')

}

return filteredContent.toString()
```

use `object to string` before groovy

Comment: I am facing performance issue with this groovy. Is there any another solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late. If still waiting for answer, try this.
It's done in dataweave only.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv header=false
---
payload[3..-1] map {
    productId:$[0],
    date: $[1]
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

This link might helpful

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/dataweave

and read about below code snippet in above doc to skip the null values

%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"

Comment: %output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere" is for output which we are producing. Here data is not get loaded into transform message because of blank line. That is the reason its showing null payload